# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'minX' of undefined

Tags: openlayers, openlayers-3

Using a modification interaction, I regularily get the following error when dragging a vertice:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'minX' of undefined

A google research does not bring any valuable results. Is there any way to prevent that?

---

There seems to be a fix for ol5 
https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/pull/9036/commits, but so far none for ol3 or ol4

Comment: I think even OL5 is still affected.  That fix went into OL6 beta.

Comment: What is the recommended workaround then? Monkeypatching? Try-catch?